# Google Spreadsheet Marcro App Script Adding Delay for The Macro Functions Lists

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I have a Macro Record which calling URL fetch function which getting some metadata from the specific URL

For Example i have 12 records in the Macro and want to have like 2 seconds pause after each macro trigger.

```
function FetchMetaData() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  spreadsheet.getRange('AV4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=HtmlLang($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaCharset($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaViewport($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV10').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=Title($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV11').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaD($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV15').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaPropertyLocale($G$2)');

};
```

Where i am suppossed to add the delay function Utillty in the code above

```
Utilities.sleep(500);
```

I am trying this because the overall script macros will be to fetch the whole single domain with fecth(url) function and the number of total live checks will be near 200 sepatrate macros i have already in dropdown menus in the spreadsheet.
Once i make all macros recorded in a single macro the script above will have loke 200 records. Obviously all of them are using fetch function and running all in one will add huge amount of lag on the spreadsheet and probably some blocks based on the number of urls the site have.

I already try adding the

```
Utilities.sleep(500);
```

below the var function but this is not add a delay between fetch runner
like

```
function FetchMetaData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  Utilities.sleep(500);
```

Also try this way

```
function FetchMetaData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV4').activate();
  Utilities.sleep(3500);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=HtmlLang($G$2)');
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV6').activate();
  Utilities.sleep(3500);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaCharset($G$2)');

};
```

And this way

```
function FetchMetaData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV4').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=HtmlLang($G$2)');
  Utilities.sleep(3500);
  spreadsheet.getRange('AV6').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=MetaCharset($G$2)');
  Utilities.sleep(3500);
};
```

Also between every .activate value but the macro runn all of the functions without delay

Any idea how can i do this in more elegant way to add the delay with a few rows of code.
Should i add all Range in Loop and For Each Function to run the Sleep Delay
Or Any Help i will Appreciate
Thanks

Comment: It appears you are using a library of custom function since they are not standard Google Spreadsheet functions..  Does one formula have to complete before the next formula can be executed?

Comment: The app script function is based on fetch() all other are like a getting html or text value of special HTML tags i am looking to make audit based on fixed values 
for Example 
for html lang i have recommended value <html lang="en" the fetch get only the text value "en" if fail and is "es" this will trigger the fetcher
Some like this 
and yes this is the idea when i run the macro each function to bee exectued then wait 10 seconds till next in the order should start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function FetchMetaData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgA = sh.getRangeList(['AV4','AV6','AV9','AV10','AV11','AV15']).getRanges();
  const fA = ['=HtmlLang($G$2)','=MetaCharset($G$2)','=MetaViewport($G$2)','=Title($G$2)','=MetaD($G$2)','=MetaPropertyLocale($G$2)'];
  rgA.forEach((r,i) => {
    r.setFormula(fA[i]);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfect with some small modification to my needs to wait xx second before activate the next fetch and it's values.
Then i read a bit more and the final solution that works for me is to add
This bot additional values in the "forEach" loop like

**SpreadsheetApp.flush();**
**Utilities.sleep(xxx);**
Adding both in the loop did the trick and delay is working perfect for now

  rgA.forEach((r,i) => {
    **SpreadsheetApp.flush();**
    r.setFormula(fA[i]);
     **Utilities.sleep(5000);**
     **SpreadsheetApp.flush();**
  });